# Stable $\infty$-category of motives

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, infinity-categories, motives, motivic-homotopy

In [nLab motive](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/motive#VoevodskyMotives), it defines the derived category of motives as the full sub-$\infty$-category of the $\infty$-category of functors $\mathop{\mathrm{Fun}}(\mathrm{Cor}_k^{\mathrm{op}}, \mathcal S)$ whose objects are the functors $\mathcal F$ satisfying the following conditions:

1. $\mathcal F$ preserves finite products.
2. $\mathcal F(X) \xrightarrow{\mathcal F(p)} \mathcal F(X \times \mathbf A^1)$ is an equivalence of spaces for every smooth $k$-scheme $X$.
3. $\mathcal F$ maps elementary distinguished squares to pullback squares.

Is this $\infty$-category a stable $\infty$-category, and is its homotopy category the same as Voevodsky's triangulated category of effective motives $\mathop{\mathrm{DM}}_{\mathrm{Nis}}^{\mathrm{eff},-}(k)$? If not, then how do we define Voevodsky's triangulated categories of motives in the setting of $\infty$-categories. Any reference would help, thanks.

Comment: I think you're describing what the nlab calls $DM^{eff}_{\geq 0}(k)$, which should not be stable. Look a little further on the nlab page to Definition 3.1, where they define $DM(k)$ to be obtained from $DM^{eff}_{\geq 0}(k)$ by stabilizing with respect to the Tate motive. Then $DM(k)$ is stable, and better it is $\mathbb P^1$-stable.

Comment: Note also that the bounded above motivic category (either effective or not) is not  "reasonable" from the infinity-categorical point of view.